# Peer discovery on a custom signet (custom `signetchallenge`)

Tags: peer-discovery, signet

I'm experimenting with signet by creating a custom network with a script of my own to validate blocks (`signetchallenge` in the conf file).

I started a mini network with only a handful nodes for now, but I noticed that they connect to each other if I tell them to with a `addnode` command (or in the conf file), but then they don't seem to do any network discovery.

To clarify, I manually connect A to B and C to B, but then B never seems to tell either A or C about each other.

As far as I understand peer discovery in bitcoin, nodes should periodically ask each others peer list with `getaddr` command, and then try to connect to new nodes. Is there a reason for this not happening on signet?

Answer (score 1):

`getaddr` will gossip addresses from peers.dat and `addnode` RPC does not save addresses in it. Using `addpeeraddress` instead could be helpful in this experiment.

Comment: That's interesting, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks!